# Composing two plugins together in October CMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Okay, so I'm currently working with October CMS and am in the process of creating two custom plugins for my website. The first one is already done and creates special kind of lists that appear at various places throughout the site and the second one is a plugin that's designed to streamline the creation of technical sheets that the users will add/update on a regular basis that describes their current achievements. Now, as you probably guessed from the title, this technical sheet will use my custom list plugin. Basically, what I'd like to do is "link" the two plugins' interface together, so to speak. If you look below, I've given you a screenshot to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

[image]

In essence, I want to be able to create my lists directly from this plugin's interface and not have to do them beforehand and include them afterward. Is that possible? Also, I'm using the "builder" plugin and it doesn't necessarily have to be tabs, I just used this as an example.

Comment: I have no experience with October but I if you are mixing up models in the same form, the controller that handles the request should be able to use each of those models. Other way could be using AJAX to create lists from the plugins form.